# How to run a shell script with parameters using airflow's SSH operator

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to run a Pentaho job in a remote system using airflow. I was able to use airflow's SSH operator to SSH into remote system and run the shell script but I'm wondering how to pass parameters to the shell script.

For example the shell command looks like

sh -C "$PENT_HOME"/kitchen.sh -file="$PENT_HOME/Details.kjb" -level=Basic > $logFolder/`date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`-Details.log 2>&1

My DAG script for running a simple shell script without parameters is

```
t1 = SSHOperator(ssh_conn_id='SSH-dev',
    task_id='ssh_operator',
    command='/opt/scripts/test.sh ',
    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 0):

`command` argument takes any bash/shell command, so you can do this for example:

```py
t1 = SSHOperator(ssh_conn_id='SSH-dev',
    task_id='ssh_operator',
    command='/opt/scripts/test.sh arg1 arg2',
    dag=dag)
```

In your case:

```py
t1 = SSHOperator(ssh_conn_id='SSH-dev',
    task_id='ssh_operator',
    command='bash "$PENT_HOME"/kitchen.sh -file="$PENT_HOME/Details.kjb" -level=Basic > $logFolder/date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"-Details.log 2>&1',
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: The following code worked `t1 = SSHOperator(ssh_conn_id='SSH-dev',
    task_id='ssh_operator',
    command='source /home/test/.bash_profile; "$PENT_HOME"/kitchen.sh -file="$PENT_HOME/Details.kjb" -level=Basic > $logFolder/date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"-Details.log 2>&1',
    dag=dag)`

Comment: can we see logs on airflow UI when running this script on a remote machine?